# Azure Devops - When importing test cases through Excel (not CSV), the "steps" field becomes empty

Tags: azure-devops

I need to export test cases from a specific project and import them into a new project on a different Azure DevOps server.

To do this, I can only use Excel and cannot use any other formats, not even CSV!

So, I decided to export the test cases to Excel, made the necessary changes, and uploaded it to the new project.

The problem is that the steps of each test case are not imported! It imports all the fields correctly, except for the steps.

I decided to conduct an experiment, which involved exporting a test case and creating a new one (exactly the same except for the ID, on the same project) through publishing in Excel.

To my surprise, the same problem occurred!

In Azure DevOps, the "steps" field contains the following content:

clicar em new

avançar

clicar em fechar

fechar

When I check the content of this field in Excel, it contains the following:

clicar em new2

avançar

clicar em fechar

fechar

Is this the cause of the problem?

Can you help me solve this issue?

Best regards

Import test cases to Azure Devops from Excel.

Comment: You're boxing yourself in by saying you can only use Excel. Excel clearly doesn't work, so you're going to have to find an alternative. There are third-party tools that can handle test case migration.

Comment: Hello,

but isn't it strange that I export from Azure Devops to Excel, copy the test cases, make some changes in Excel and then re-publish to Azure Devops and it doesn't work? The steps field is empty!

For example, this process in TFS worked fine!